# Search one word containing # with *

Tags: search

I would like to search the word under my cursor. For this, I tried to press `*`.
But, if the word I want to search is `#foo`, as an example, vim only searches
word `foo` (without hash), so it fails.

In fact, the `#` is not considered in the word, which is confirmed when I try to
go to the next word with `w`.

Do you know how I can search effectively `#titi` by pressing `*` on my keyboard?

Comment: Besides warnings about changing `iskeyword` consider this: how should all of the non-keyword characters that are fully or partially pattern atoms (i.e. they are special in a regex) be handled. Existing `*` functionality doesn't need to worry about how to handle `*`, `?`, `(`, etc. That functionality would need to be well defined.

Comment: for the rare cases I need this, I usually just use `g*` instead of `*` and continue jumping using `n` until I find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What is considered to be part of a word is defined, I think, by `iskeyword`. You can try to change this setting to include `#` and see if it solves your case.

More info: `:help 'iskeyword'`

Comment: Do be careful with this, as it does affect a *lot* of things

Comment: Of course it does affect a lot of things!
How can i change keywords just for # and - (i want for exemple #foo-bar to be just one word)? i tried before but i did not succeed.
The problem is that i also want to use tags with CTRL + ], so maybe i cannot do 
        set iskeyword="" 
as far as i understand.
Mathieu

Answer (score 1):

You can use a visual selection first to highlight all the text you want to search for, then run your search. If `#foo` is surrounded by whitespace, it's even easier; you could simply do `viW*`.

Reference: `:help v_star-default`

Note: This is *Neovim specific* does not work in Vim

Comment: That's neovim only, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A solution without changing the `iskeyword` option or using `*` would be to put the whole white-space delimited word (see [`:help WORD`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#WORD)) under the cursor with <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> (see [`:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A)) into search, or:

```
/<C-R><C-A><CR>
```

Now `*` (as opposed to `g*`) also has the nice touch of wrapping the word in boundaries like this `\<foo\>`. If you want to match `#foo` but not `#foobar`, you need to add them yourself:

```
/\<<C-R><C-A>\><CR>
```

This is a little more typing than a simple `*` but not too much (I think) for occasional use.

If you need to search for strings like `#foo` frequently, I'd suggest creating a mapping like `nnoremap <lhs> /\<^R^A\><CR>` where `<lhs>` is the key you want to use and `^R^A` is produced by pressing the sequence <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>.